# Conditional variance: $ \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X\mid\theta]\mid P) = \operatorname{Var}(X\mid P) - \operatorname{Var}(X\mid \theta)$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Why does it hold:
$ \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X\mid\theta]\mid P) =  \operatorname{Var}(X\mid P) -  \operatorname{Var}(X\mid\theta)$, where $\theta$ are normal random variables? 
It looks a bit like projection theorem, but I can't apply it here.

Comment: What does $P\subset \theta$ mean if they are both "normal random variables"?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean $P \subset \theta$. I have edited the question.

Comment: By Law of Total Variance, $\operatorname{Var}[X\mid P] = \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}[X\mid P, \Theta]\mid P] + \operatorname{Var}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid P, \Theta]\mid P]$. When $\sigma(P) \subset \sigma(\Theta)$, i.e. $P$ is $\Theta$-measurable, you can rearrange - but still missing something..